# Dynamically change and check variable in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables

I have the following code:

**JS:**

```
var flag = 0;
funct(){//makes changes on css
flag=0;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form onsubmit="if(flag==1)return funct()">
```

**PHP:**

```
if(somethingIsOK){
    echo "<script>flag=1;</script>"; //should use new css which comes with funct()
}else{//do something else with keeping the existing css}
```

I want this structure, but I could not use the variable `flag` like I wanted to. I have tried making `flag` static but it did not work.

Comment: you cannot use the same variable both in JS and PHP

Comment: I assume the first part of the code is Javascript. Is this right?

Comment: Post your html + js on http://jsfiddle.net/ and update your question.

Comment: Dynamically change and check what variable? What condition? What is it you're trying to *do*? And post your (relevant/[sscce](http://sscce.org/)) HTML *here*, not just at JS Fiddle.

Comment: I am sorry guys all are js, just if else parts are php, yes first part is js

Comment: @vladkras You can, with some effort. See my answer.

Comment: @lazyCrab that's right, but you still use ancient approach for it, css can be changed dinamically

Comment: @vladkras I know it is a bad approach, but I am just answering what the poster asked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hidden field to set/unset flag

```
<input type="hidden" name="flag" id="flag" value="1" />
```

javascript

```
var flag = document.getElementById('flag').value;
funct(){//makes changes on css
document.getElementById('flag').value=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the way you do it, but the answer is to delete `var` before flag to make it global:

```
flag = 0;
```

### [proof](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/cWe8K/)

**EDIT**

1. if you want to prevent form submit your `funct()` must `return
   false;`
2. maybe you try

   ```
   if(somethingIsOK){
       echo "<script type="text/javascript">flag=1;</script>"; 
   }else{
       echo "<script type="text/javascript">flag=0;</script>"; 
   }
   ```

and again: it's a very-very bad idea to mix php and JS like that

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily use the same variable in both PHP and JS. What you can do however is make a `<input type="hidden">` with the name flag and the value of the variable and then read it in both PHP and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Its bad idea to use constructions like this, but if you realy want use some global variable you can assign it to window object property, i.e.:

```
window.flag = 0;
```

And use this variable(window.flag) everywhere you need it.

Comment: You are missing the point. The second part is in PHP while the first is in JS.

Comment: It doesn't matter, all js parts will be parsed after php.

Comment: Topicstarter doesn't used *flag* in php, he used it only in JS parts, no hidden field needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag = 0;
funct(){//makes changes on css
flag=0;}
```

try

```
var flag = 0;
function funct(){  // <<<<< function
//makes changes on css
flag=0;}
```